# assistance with technique for htaccess debugging

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to debug an .htaccess file using shared hosting. I've come across http://blog.tolleiv.de/2010/01/debugging-mod_rewrite/. I'd like to use the technique mentioned to echo out the incoming query string

So far I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !vardump
RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain.con/$1?vardump&reqhost=%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

When I put this in my public_html/.htacess I get

```
http://mydomain.com/?vardump&reqhost=
```

in my browser bar. Any idea why the incoming request is not displayed?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Anubhava. So what is the best way to print out or see the query. I want to be able to see the incoming query then  after a rewrite print out the modified query?

Comment: Your current rule will allow you to debug. Try opening this URL: `http://mydomain.com/contacts?foo=bar` and it will show you original and modified query in your browser. It will show you `http://mydomain.com/contacts?vardump&reqhost=foo=bar&foo=bar` in your browser.

Comment: Thanks again, if you can put this in as a question I can upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current rule will allow you to debug. Try opening this URL: `http://mydomain.com/contacts?foo=bar` then it will show you original and modified query in your browser. It will show `http://mydomain.com/contacts?vardump&reqhost=foo=bar&foo=bar` in your browser.

However if you are loading `http://mydomain.com` as per your rule it will indeed become `http://mydomain.com/?vardump&reqhost=` as both `$1` and `%{QUERY_STRING}` will be empty. Also better not to use `R=301` for testing, make it `R=302`. Clear you browser cache once before you test.

Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.